# How do I verify if a number is a valid Twitter ID?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm randomly generating a large number, and I want to check if it corresponds to a legitimate Twitter ID. I have checked the Twitter API, but I can't seem to find the appropriate method to use here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the GET `users/lookup` via the api it takes either a user_id or a screen_name https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup

Comment: @computerScienceLearner did this solve your question or are you looking for something else? if it did could you accept my answer? Thanks!